# What is Gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build-automation

Gradle is a bit confusing to me, and also for any new Android developer. Can anyone explain what Gradle in Android Studio is and what its purpose is? Why is it included in Android Studio?

Comment: See http://www.gradle.org/

Comment: To answer _why_ you would want a build tool such as Gradle, check out [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/the-f5-key-is-not-a-build-process.html) from Jeff Atwood.

Comment: When someone asks a question on here that yes, does have a lot of links in Google about it, what they are really asking is for someone to answer the question with **plain language** and to put it in **context**, such as why do we need it, who will use it most, do we need to know it to build Android apps in Android Studio, etc. Because most often the links you find about it on Google are in "tech-speak" and for a beginner this is confusing.

Comment: Also check [what-is-real-android-studio-gradle-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391708/what-is-real-android-studio-gradle-version/51392464#51392464)

Comment: Gradle is the most annoying part of being an Android developer. When it asks you to upgrade your project to the latest version of gradle, think twice about it. Also make sure you have a backup first. In my experience almost every time I upgrade to a newer version it causes hours of searching the web trying to find out why it broke my project. Not fun!

Answer (score 1665, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Gradle is a build system.

#### Long Answer

Before Android Studio you were using [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) for your development purposes, and, chances are, you didn't know how to build your Android [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) without Eclipse.

You can do this on the command line, but you have to learn what each tool ([dx](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dx/info) and [AAPT](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2)) does in the SDK.
Eclipse saved us all from these low-level, but important, fundamental details by giving us their own build system.

Now, have you ever wondered why the `res` folder is in the same directory as your `src` folder?

This is where the build system enters the picture. The build system automatically takes all the source files (`.java` or `.xml`), then applies the appropriate tool (e.g., takes `.java` class files and converts them to `.dex` files), and groups all of them into one compressed file - our beloved APK.

This build system uses some conventions: an example of one is to specify the directory containing the source files (in Eclipse it is `\src` folder) or resources files (in Eclipse it is `\res` folder).

Now, in order to automate all these tasks, there has to be a script; you can write your own build system using shell scripting in Linux or batch files syntax in Windows. Got it?

Gradle is another **build system** that takes the best features from other build systems and combines them into one. It is improved based off of their shortcomings. It is a **JVM-based build system**. That means you can write your own script in Java, which Android Studio makes use of.

One cool thing about Gradle is that it is a **plugin-based system**. This means if you have your own programming language and you want to automate the task of building some package (output like a [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file for Java) from sources, then you can write a complete plugin in Java or [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) (or [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language)), see [here](https://blog.gradle.org/kotlin-meets-gradle)), and distribute it to the rest of the world.

#### Why did Google use it?

Google saw one of the most advanced build systems on the market and realized that you could write scripts of your own with little-to-no learning curve, and without learning Groovy or any other new language. So they wrote the Android plugin for Gradle.

You must have seen the `build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kts` file(s) in your project. That is where you can write scripts to automate your tasks. The code you saw in these files is Groovy or Kotlin code. If you write `System.out.println("Hello Gradle!");` then it will print on your console.

#### What can you do in a build script?

A simple example is that you have to copy some files from one directory to another before the actual build process happens. A Gradle build script can do this.

Comment: Gradle is coolest thing if we use it , example I had built system using gradle which based on task run picks dev or prod version of code and auto commits apk in  svn and then emails that apk and message to email ids configured in gradle itself. So my manual tasks are over.

Comment: I have to say that Gradle was giving me issues when taking an AndroidStudio project from one location to another. Mismatches of versions, missing modules, whatnot... it was giving me hard time. I ended up re-creating the project skeleton and cutting/pasting the parts of code that were from the old project to the new one. And this is under Windows for both sources and destination. I am going to move it now under a Linux-based lab.

Comment: What I don't understand is why gradle tries to connect to Internet for every single project that I make or even every single time I want to compile

Comment: @user1700737 : To generate simple apk android studio is provided over gradle so if you ask me then there is no need to go into internals of gradle as far as simple apk generation is cencerned. Gradle is build system and helps to achieve complex,dependent tasks in one go and automated way.

Comment: In which language is build.gradle written?

Comment: @M.S.
Quote from the comment above by: Gagandeep Singh
"The code you saw in these files is groovy code."
Groovy is a Java extension: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29

Comment: "This means if you have your own programming language ...you can write a complete plugin in Java or Groovy". There's no such thing as "your own programming language". You have to use Groovy.

Comment: You can write your own plugin in Java Or Groovy

Comment: Another key advantage of gradle over the pre Android studio build system(s) is dependency management. Previously to use an Android library in a project, one would have to download the source code, add it to your project and compile it with your project. Instead, with gradle one can add a single line to the build.gradle and gradle will then download the compiled library from a public repository and add it to your project. Some examples: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/android-libraries-use-every-project  This also works for standard Java jar files instead of putting them in the lib directory.

Comment: So is gradle just the background process that compiles the code I have written? Also, after looking at lots of other answers, they mention dependencies. What are those? THanks so much Gagandeep!

Comment: Yes gradle is another background process which compiles code.Dependency is nothing but a jar file path or source code path which you wish to use in your project in simple format.

Comment: Gradle is a terrible build system.  In using Android Studio I want it to take care of the build.  I don't understand why adding some classes forces Gradle to do a sync before it can be useful.  Working with Visual Studio by comparison is awesome (or even X-Code) - no crappy extras needed.  The IDE builds the project and solution without the need to tinker around in random files for settings that the Android build process needs at times or through updates of old projects.  Gradle is the worst part of the Android experience.

Answer (score 177):

It's the new build tool that Google wants to use for Android. It's being used due to it being more extensible, and useful than [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant). It is meant to enhance developer experience.

You can view a talk by Xavier Ducrohet from the Android Developer Team at [Google I/O](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0) here.

There is also another talk on Android Studio by Xavier and Tor Norbye, also [during Google I/O here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmv1dTnhLH4).

Comment: I thought IntelliJ already knew how to build Android projects without the need for another build system.

Comment: So is gradle just the background process that compiles the code I have written? Also, after looking at lots of other answers, they mention dependencies. What are those? THanks so much daniel!

Comment: @user5562706 It doesn't compile the code, but it's responsible for calling the executable that does compile your code. After compiling your code, it can then run another task to package it up, another to copy it to a directory of your choosing, then maybe another to upload it to a server somewhere... It's those sorts of tasks Gradle, or any build system, will do.

Answer (score 76):

**Gradle** is a build system running on **Android Studio**.

In other languages for example:

- [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) of **Java**
- [Rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake) of **Ruby**
- [A-A-P](http://www.a-a-p.org/) of **C**
- [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) of **.NET**
- [Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) in **Linux**

Comment: When you said `Gradle` is similar to `make`, I just got its concept

Comment: PHING of **PHP**

Comment: One of the fastest ways I've found to learn what an unknown tool does and where it falls in the pipeline, is to type into Google the name of the tool and "vs". The results will usually show "X vs Y" where Y is some other tool you might be more familiar with.

Comment: webpack for javascript

Comment: Linux is not a programming language. It is mostly used for [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29). Perhaps *"Make of C on Linux"*?

Comment: Perhaps add [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) for [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)? And [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) for [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) (web)?

Answer (score 34):

Gradle is one type of **build tool** that builds the source code of the program. So it's an important part of Android Studio, and needs to be installed before starting developing your application.

We do not have to install it separately, because the Android Studio does it for us, when we make our first project.

Comment: What do you mean by building the source code of the program? Isn't that the job of a developer?

Comment: This answer is completely wrong in the way it is worded. 

Gradle is the packaging tool that comes bundled with Android Studio, so what it takes care of is building the apk.

The source code is always being built by the compiler and nothing else.

Comment: Yet from another question it sounds like Gradle won't work properly without a reliable internet conneciton, does this mean I have to throw away Android Studio until that is fixed?

Comment: @committedandroider: the job of a developer is to _write_ the source code, not _build_ it. In system developement we use the word "Build" to mean the process of _packaging_ the _compiled_ source code into a final _product_ (a _package_ or an _executable_)

Comment: @MestreLion lol I was pretty confused back then because people used 'building' in reference to writing source code for their projects- i built this chat server, this app to...

Answer (score 32):

***Definition:*** Gradle can be described as a structured building mechanism where it provides a developer with the tools and flexibility to manage the resources of a project to create builds that are *smaller in size*, *targeting specific requirements* for certain devices of certain configurations

---

#### Basic configurations

1. `minimumSdk`
2. `maximumSdk`
3. `targettedSdk`
4. `versionCode`
5. `versionName`

---

#### Libraries

We can add Android libraries or any other third-party libraries in addition as per requirements. It is easy and was a tedious task earlier. If the library does not fit for the existing project, the developer is shown a log where the person can find an appropriate solution to make changes to the project so that the library can be added. It's just one line of dependency.

---

***Generating varieties of builds***

Combining build types with build flavours to get varieties of build variants

```
 ====================                         ====================
|     BuildTypes     |                       |   ProductFlavours  |
 --------------------  ====================== --------------------
|  Debug,Production  |      ||       ||      | Paid,Free,Demo,Mock|
 ====================       ||       ||       ==================== 
                            ||       ||
                            VV       VV
 =================================================================
|           DebugPaid, DebugFree, DebugDemo, DebugMock            |
|  ProductionPaid, ProductionFree, ProductionDemo, ProductionMock |
 =================================================================
```

---

#### Reducing size

Gradle helps in reducing the size of the generated build by removing the unused resources also unused things from integrated libraries.

---

#### Managing permissions

We can *specify* certain permissions for certain builds by adding certain permissions in certain scenarios based on requirements.

---

#### Builds for certain devices

We can manage generating build for certain devices that include certain densities and certain API levels. This helps in product deployments in the app store according to requirements across multiple types of devices.

---

#### Good reference

*[Vogella Tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html)*

Answer (score 29):

You can find everything you need to know about Gradle here:
[Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

> #### Goals of the new Build System
>
> The goals of the new build system are:
>
> - Make it easy to reuse code and resources
> - Make it easy to create several variants of an application, either for multi-apk distribution or for different flavors of an application
> - Make it easy to configure, extend and customize the build process
> - Good IDE integration
>
> #### Why Gradle?
>
> Gradle is an advanced build system as well as an advanced build
> toolkit allowing to create custom build logic through plugins.
>
> Here are some of its features that made us choose Gradle:
>
> - Domain Specific Language (DSL) to describe and manipulate the build logic
> - Build files are Groovy based and allow mixing of declarative elements through the DSL and using code to manipulate the DSL elements
>   to provide custom logic.
> - Built-in dependency management through Maven and/or Ivy.
> - Very flexible. Allows using best practices but doesn’t force its own way of doing things.
> - Plugins can expose their own DSL and their own API for build files to use.
> - Good Tooling API allowing IDE integration

Comment: Re *"everything you need"*: No, it is missing information about [DX](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/the-path-to-dx-deprecation.html) (and D8 for that matter).

Answer (score 27):

Gradle is a [build system](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Edww4s/articles/build_systems.html). **Build systems** are software tools designed to automate the process of program compilation. Build systems come in various forms, and are used for a variety of software build tasks. While their primary goal is to efficiently create executables.

Another related term is *build automation* which is the process of automating the creation of a software build and the associated processes including: compiling computer source code into binary code, packaging binary code, and running automated tests.

Few similar build system for other languages are (see complete list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software)):

1. [Apache Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) and [Apache Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) - Java
2. [sbt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbt_(software)#History) - for [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) ([Play Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Framework), etc.)
3. [A-A-P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-A-P) - [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)-based build tool
4. [Rake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_(software)) (Apache Builder) - [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)
5. [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) for [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure)

Answer (score 21):

At the risk of being discursive I think behind this is the question of why the Android Studio / Gradle experience is so bad.

Typical [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) experience:

- download project with dependencies listed in *project.clj*.
- [Leiningen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiningen_(software)) gets the dependencies thanks to [Clojars](https://clojars.org/) and [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven).
- Project compiles.

Typical Android Studio / Gradle experience:

- "Import my [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) project".
- OK, project imported.
- Gradle is doing its thing ...  wait ... wait ... wait ... Gradle has finished.
- Compile ... can't compile, because I don't know what an X is / can't find Y library.

I'm not sure this is Gradle's fault exactly. But the "import from Eclipse project" seems pretty flaky. For all of Gradle's alleged sophistication and the virtues of a build system, Android Studio just doesn't seem to import the build dependencies or build process from Eclipse very well.

It doesn't tell you when it's failed to import a complete dependency graph. The Android Studio gives no useful help or tips as to how to solve the problem. It doesn't tell you where you can manually look in the Eclipse folders. It doesn't tell you which library seems to be missing. Or help you search Maven, etc. for them.

In 2016 things like Leiningen / Clojars, or Node.js's [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)), or Python's [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29), or the Debian apkg (and I'm sure many similar package managers for other languages and systems) all work beautifully ... missing dependencies are thing of the past.

Except with Android. Android Studio is now the only place where I still seem to experience missing-dependency hell.

I'm inclined to say this is Google's fault. They broke the Android ecosystem (and thousands of existing Android projects / online tutorials) when they cavalierly decided to shift from Eclipse to Android Studio / Gradle without producing a robust conversion process. People whose projects work in Eclipse aren't adapting them to Android Studio (presumably because it's a pain for them). And people trying to use those projects in Android Studio are hitting the same issues.

And anyway, if Gradle is this super-powerful build system, why am I still managing a whole lot of other dependencies in the SDK Manager? Why can't a project that needs, say, the [NDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_NDK) specify this in its Gradle file so that it gets automatically installed and built-against when needed? Why is NDK special? Similarly for target platforms? Why am I installing them explicitly in the IDE rather than just checking my project against them and having this all sorted for me behind the scenes?

Comment: I fully agree that Gradle is a terrible build system.  It is the component that makes Android Studio far worse than X-Code or Visual Studio.  I realise these must "build" the system behind the scenes but I'm not really required to know/care/tinker with their internals.  Gradle on the other hand seems to break with every Android Studio update and bogs down the system even just adding a class.  No other IDE does that.

Answer (score 15):

Gradle is an advanced build system as well as an advanced build toolkit allowing to create custom build logic through plugins!

**Advantages:**

- DSL - [Domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), based on [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29)
- [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) - Directed acyclic graph
- Incremental builds
- Extensible domain model
- Gradle is always up to date
- Before a task is being execute, Gradle takes a snapshot of its task’s input and output.
- In case the snapshot has changed or it doesn’t exists, Gradle will
  re-execute this task.

**Manifest entries**

Through the DSL it is possible to configure the following
manifest entries:

**Build variant**

By default, the Android plugin automatically sets up the project to
build both a debug and a release version of the application.

**Dependencies**

1. Local Dependencies:

> If you have binary archives in your local filesystem that a module
> depends on, such as JAR files, you can declare these dependencies in
> the build file for that module.

2. Remote Dependencies:

> First the repository must be added to the list, and then the
> dependency must be declared in a way that Maven or Ivy declare their
> artifacts.

Answer (score 13):

Gradle is to the [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) JVM language what [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) is to Java.   Basically, it's Groovy's build tool.  Unlike Ant, it's based on the full Groovy language.  You can, for example, write Groovy script code in the Gradle script to do something rather than relying on a [domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

I don't know [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)'s specific integration, but imagine you could "extend" Groovy such that you could write specific "build" language primitives and they just became part of the Groovy language.  (Groovy's metaprogramming is a whole discussion unto itself.)   IntelliJ and Google could use Gradle to build a very high-level build language, yet, it's a language build on an expandable, open standard.

Comment: it's not "Groovys build tool" - it's a multi purpose build tool whose DSL is build on top of groovy

Answer (score 12):

Gradle is an advanced build toolkit for Android that manages dependencies and allows you to define custom build logic. Features are like

- Customize, configure, and extend the build process.
- Create multiple [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) files for your app with different features using the same project.
- Reuse code and resources.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html)

Answer (score 11):

Gradle is an automated build toolkit that can integrate into lots of different environments, not only for Android projects.

Here are few things that you can do with Gradle.

- **Minimal configuration required for new projects because Gradle has default configurations for your Android Studio projects.**
- **Dependency declaration. You can declare dependency JAR files or library files that is hosted on the local or remote server.**
- **Gradle automatically generates a test directory and a test APK file from your project's source.**
- **If you add all the necessary information, such as `keyPassword` and `keyAlias`, to your Gradle build file, you can use Gradle to generate signed APK files.**
- **Gradle can generate multiple APK files with different packages and build configurations from a single module.**

Answer (score 10):

In Android Studio, Gradle is a custom build tool used to build Android packages ([APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) files) by managing dependencies and providing custom build logic.

APK file (Android Application package) is a specially formatted ZIP file which contains

- Byte code
- Resources (images, UI, [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), etc.)
- Manifest file

An APK file gets signed and pushed to the device using [ADB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_Debug_Bridge_(ADB)) (Android Debug Bridge) where it gets executed.

Answer (score 8):

Gradle is a build tool custom and is used for building APK files. It is also known as an application package kit.

Comment: What do you mean by *"build tool custom"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38548948/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 7):

Gradle is what makes it possible to automate the building of complex Android projects that involve 10s of thousands of lines of code from multiple sources, projects, libraries, etc.  It can conditionally generate multiple optimized APKs based on a plethora of configuration specifications - if you are interested, the other answers provide more details of this aspect of Gradle.

However, if you're new to Android development, Gradle in 99% of cases is what **stops** your project from building.  It is an inscrutable, complex system that effectively obfuscates the Android build process and essentially renders it unavailable to inexperienced developers, ie in order to build a simple entry-level Android App the unsuspecting newbie might need to study and understand many things that they didn't bargain for such as:

- Android APK structure and ecosystem
- Android Studio
- Java Classpaths and dependencies
- Groovy
- Gradle build scripts
- Many other complex and interesting technologies

All these things are interesting and useful for Android developers to know, but they are far from easy and present a formidable barrier to entry. I suspect that what inspired the OP to ask this question is the feeling of frustration that inevitably hits the neophyte developer after spending way too long trying to get a simple app to build and being continually thwarted by Gradle. The problem is perversely exacerbated by the overwhelming quantity of highly technical documentation that is available for all these technologies.  Also for a large amount of development needs, Gradle is overkill.

An alternative is to write a shell script that builds your project by automating the tools available in the Android SDK.  The virtues of this approach are many, for starters, it's probably the best way to study and understand the build process and the Android ecosystem, and it allows you to completely control how your app is built.  However, this approach is more suitable for deeply irredeemable tech-heads than it is to inexperienced noobs trying out android.

What is conspicuous by its absence (please inform me if there is such a thing) is an entry-level, lightweight IDE with a reduced feature set that simultaneously simplifies the build process while not obscuring it (so not Netbeans or Eclipse) it could possibly still use Gradle (what was wrong with Ant).  It should make it easy to generate APKs that conform to a few common configurations and use a project structure that can evolve to a full Android Studio project should you decide to take it that way.

Answer (score 6):

By **@Brian Gardner:**

Gradle is an extensive build tool and dependency manager for programming projects. It has a domain-specific language based on Groovy. Gradle also provides build-by-convention support for many types of projects including Java, Android and Scala.

**Feature of Gradle:**

1. Dependency Management
2. Using Ant from Gradle
3. Gradle Plugins
4. Java Plugin
5. Android Plugin
6. Multi-Project Builds

Comment: What does "Brian Gardner" refer to?

Answer (score 3):

In plain terms, Gradle is a tool provided by Android Studio in order to implement two important processes:

1. Build our projects
2. Package AndroidManifest.xml, res folder, and binary code into a specially formatted zip file called APK

Answer (score 1):

Gradle = Groovy + Cradle

Reference: [Hans Dockter forum comment](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-is-gradle-called-gradle/3226)

The confusion is a bit unnecessary when it could have just been called "Build" or something in Android Studio.

We like to make things difficult for ourselves in the development community.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is an easily customizable build system that supports building by a convention model. Gradle is written in Java, but the build language is Groovy DSL (domain spec language). Gradle not only supports multi-project builds, but it also supports dependencies like Ivy and Maven. Gradle also can support building non-Java projects.

https://medium.com/@ravirajdesai501/what-is-gradle-442458dd7ec1

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is like a version of `make` that puts features before usability, which is why you and 433k readers can't even work out that it's a build system.

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple answer for that,

Gradle is a build system, which is responsible for code compilation, testing, deployment and conversion of the code into . dex files and hence running the app on the device. As Android Studio comes with Gradle system pre-installed, there is no need to install additional runtime softwares to build our project.

Answer (score 1):

**Gradle and Android**

[Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html) is an [open-source](https://github.com/gradle/gradle) build automation tool. Gradle supports Java and Kotlin for Android

```
source files -> build tools -> output file(.apk, .jar, .aar ...)
```

You can use more low level build tools like `javac`, `DX, D8`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65408173/4770877), `aapt`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259810/4770877), sign tools ...

Gradle is more hight level tool which do all this stuff under the hood. It has next advantages:

- dependency manager[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61185954/4770877)
- uses `Domain Specific Language(DSL)` on Groovy or Kotlin to expose current settings or to customize/extends the build process. For example you are able to write some tasks and share them through any projects

[[gradle vs gradlew]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49076817/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

i will explain it in terms of java in simple way possible.

let suppose we have simple hello world project (HelloWorld.java). In order to run the project we need to compile it (HelloWorld.class). Then we will run it in JVM (java virtual machine).

[image: compiling java code]

The process of compiling a code can be done using JDK (Java development kit) which comes with javac.exe (java compiler command). It compiles Java source files (.java) into bytecode class files (.class).

[image]

You call javac.exe with list of all the .java source files. For example for single source file

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

to Compile multiple Java source files

```
javac Program1.java Program2.java Program3.java
```

which is not too much fun to do since once you start making big projects you might start using functionality provided by third party (jar files). for example
Compile a source file which depends on an external library:

```
javac -classpath mail.jar EmailSender.java
```

Compile a source file which depends on an external multiple library:(where Myprogram.java is your source file which depends on multiple libraries)

```
javac -cp lib1.jar;lib2.jar;lib3.jar MyProgram.java
```

remember sometimes source file depends on 100 and 1000 of multiple libraries which make manual compilation a real hard work. To solve this problem we have Built tools for example **Gradle**, **Maven** (which makes compilation error free process and and be done many times easily)

Other uses of Built tools like Gradle are

- testing your source code is easy
- packaging your application in to    format so that it can be
  published and deployed is easy

Answer (score 0):

A Definition of Gradle is a file where we can put the dependency of 3rd party library and some systems config files like core and components, etc with version.

We have a project base gradle and a module base gradle, The project base gradle has all project-related info with the respective repository, kotlin version, and the plugin info that we used for the projects.

In Module-related gradle, it consumes the plugin used for the module, module config like debug or release, type of build variant, binding info if we used, and the list of core and 3rd party dependencies. Just make sure to choose the latest version of the dependency.