# Error:Connection timed out in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I just upgraded to Android Studio version 2.2.1 and a project running well, now I am getting the following error message:

```
Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.
```

I know that there are another questions similar to this, but is not the same case. I don't use any proxy or whatever.

Comment: temp solution: try to go with "offline mode" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27815316/870674

Comment: Try with a Reset, work for me...

Comment: Reset? Cleaning the project? Restart and invalidate cache?

Comment: The typical and old way close/open again the program ;)

Answer (score 3):

go to this link you find your answer :
[AndroidStudio gradle proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy)
or
file > setting > proxy > mark auto detect proxy

Comment: This is the default setting. Question mentioned no proxy was used anyway