# Import Eclipse Project to Android studio project by python

Tags: python, gradle

1. I export Google Android Project from unity, it's an Eclipse Project
2. I want to import this Eclipse Project to Android Studio Project by command line or use python script

I had imported the Eclipse Project into Android Studio Project by IDE, but don't know how to import by command line, I'm not familiar with Gradle, Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question needs to be more focused to get quality help from SO. Broad questions like yours are difficult to answer. If you succeeded in importing the project from Studio, why do you need to do it from command line again?

Comment: I want to generate apk use python scripts. All the process will finished by scripts, and I need not to operate it.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio The whole point of gradle is to replace your python script to make building apks automated and easy to modify