# Android studio 2.1.3 not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated Android studio from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3 and after that it is not working. It is showing only refreshing.

May be it's a stupid question but I do not know why I am facing this issue from today morning.

[image]

Comment: Graddle´s references? Are you trying to open an old project?

Comment: yes it's an old project.

Comment: Android development tools are almost always getting broken right after update. Prepare to fix them regularly :) as for android studio, try re-syncing, check build.gradle, google for errors and so on...

Comment: @Krishna Meena. Check you graddle´s references...

Comment: I have the same situation with you. I just wait for it. And after a while, it fixed itself. And make sure your computer is connected to the internet because I saw the Android Studio downloading some jars.

Comment: @EliasMP what's graddle´s references.. ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio Maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what's wrong with this, actually I have updated gradle wrapper to 3.0 from 2.14.1 and it is causing this problem so reverting back it to 2.14.1 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Build > Clean project
2. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Maybe this will help