# Android studio won't stop building gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I started watching tutorials today about Android studio,so i downloaded and wanted to run the app just to check if it works.

First it returned `init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB`,but emulator opened.However eventually emulator returned error about process,so i closed it.
  I read that that error may be caused because of screen resolution so i changed it to 800x600.

After changing that i wanted to run the app again,but the run button was disabled and in the bottom i saw this `Gradle building`,so i stopped that.Now it won't stop `Stopping - Gradle Build Running`

Comment: You could try to run the Gradle wrapper from the command line in the directory of your project

Comment: @cricket_007 can you explain how and why?

Comment: Open up a terminal window to your project, and try `.\gradlew build`. I don't know why, but at least seeing a Gradle log output is more useful than an obscure UI message

Comment: There's also an "Invalidate cache and restart" option in the top menu that you could try.

Comment: @cricket_007 it started downloading something from  https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
and is now outputing lines of dots.I have done that 2 times.

Comment: Right. That is the Gradle binaries and sources. [Gradle is needed by Android Studio to compile your apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio).  I do not know why it would do that more than once.