# How to create a sample Java application using Tone Analyzer (IBM Watson)

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I'm new to IBM Watson.

I'm interested in using Tone Analyzer and I want to create a simple Java application with it.

I've read the documentation and got here

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/tone-analyzer

I don't understand however what steps I need to do from here.

The installation readme is not clear at all.

My goal is to analyze the simple text from the mail in the example shown.

I use Eclipse as IDE, I want to setup a project doing it.

Comment: Your actual issue is that you don't know what Maven or Gradle are. Since you are starting from scratch, go for Gradle as it's newer. Learn to create a simple Gradle project using Eclipse: http://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/gradle/java-project-gradle-eclipse-integration-example  -- then add this library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Gradle in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio)   -- not an exact match, because Android, but basically what OP needs.

Comment: I've found this guide here https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/bluemix-watson-apis-quickstart-using-java-sdk-version-2016/

I don't know where I can find the server console output. The results should be there