# Gradle sync on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Regarding Gradle Sync on Android Studio.

- what does it do?
- Why it is needed?
- How to debug it?
- where to find docs on the subject?

Projects that compile fine from command line have issues with gradle sync instead. I'm interested in the interaction with the android studio environment, cause it's clearly an operation not needed for the sake of compiling a project.

Comment: The same [**Post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio)

Comment: @R.García i'm asking specifically about the gradle sync operation, not gradle in general, whose doc is here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: @AndrewBloom Ok, it was a confusion

Comment: @KarthikVenkatraman I know what gradle is, and i can use it on command line. I'm asking about Gradle Sync, as clearly stated on the question.