# gradlew clean vs gradlew clear what is the difference

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I wrote by mistake `gradlew clear` instead of `gradlew clean` in my react-native project's `android` folder, and I see that it does some serious work. So what is this doing and what is the difference between `gradlew`'s `clear` vs `clean`?   I could not find documentation.

Also it would be good to understand: When I run `gradlew.bat` it seems I'm running a java class. Where is the `clean` and where is the `clear` java class?  Or is this some internal command of the gradlew (java) program?

Comment: Tried searching the docs? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html  Clean, at least, is specific to the plugins that are used, such as removing the build artifacts in Java/Android

Comment: I've never seen the task `clear` in Gradle or any 3rd party plugin, so maybe you should add the output when calling `gradlew clear` to your question. Regarding the second part of your question, I'll suggest you to get some insight on Gradle starting with the popular question [What is Gradle in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16754643).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the serious work is "loading 6/6 projects" and then after a while of churning away it says:

```
C:\dev\devreact\noam\android>gradlew clear
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'clear' not found in root project 'noam'. 
Some candidates are: 'clean'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 49.374 secs
```

So there is no `gradlew clear`

About the clean: you can glean much information by reading this: https://www.labkey.org/Documentation/wiki-page.view?name=gradleClean

The Gradle docs say nothing about cleaning and do not really explain the internals of Gradle.