# Activity_main.xml not showing and Gradle doesn't finish initial build

Tags: android, gradle

Hi im kinda new to android studio and im trying to learn from tutorials on youtube but i cant seem to do it because the activity_main.xml is not opening up and stuck at waiting for build to finish... ive been waiting for like an hour now and not certain what to do i also tried reinstalling it but nothing happened and stuck at this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Design view need to finish the Gradle build.

You can use this solution-

add this line in `gradle.propertise`

```
    org.gradle.daemon=true
    org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Then build again.

This is Gradle properties [image]

**Edit**

Check out this photo. Does your gradle setting look like that-
[image]

Comment: Im sorry im completely new to android studio and totally have no experience and dont know how can i do that

Comment: The heck i dont even know what gradle is

Comment: [Check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio)

Comment: I read it but i still dont know where should i put those codes

Comment: my settings also have no Cradle in it

Comment: Ok so i found it and we have the same Cradle but the preview still doesnt work

Comment: Now check the offline work and hit ok.. then build project again

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio preview needs **at least one success build** in order to show the Preview.

Go to `Build -> Rebuild project` then check if there is any issues then run the app on an emulator (Or a real device) after, you'll be able to see the preview if your dependencies has no problem.

Comment: I tried but nothing happen i also clicked Clean Project and nothing

Comment: Is this the first time you create a project? Would you add the build.gradle file codes in your question? Use edit button. It seems like it needs to rebuild the project, however, you better check to see if there is an issue or something.

Comment: yes this is my first time creating and using android studio and I don't know how to add build.gradle file codes. my edit button is all blacked out and only undo, find, macros, and Convert Indents are only active

Comment: There must be some issues in your project which it couldn't resolve that. That's why this is happening. You'll have to use `Build -> build project` and then if you saw any errors in the logs, paste it in your question. By editing, I meant editing your question and adding more screenshots or logs.