# activity_main.xml for android studio stuck on loading

Tags: android, android-studio, loading

I just downloaded Android Studio to make an app for my STEM competition. I tried making an app, opened the activity_main.xml file, but it is stuck on loading! It says, `

> "Gradle: download gradle-5.6.4-all.zip...".

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are connected to the internet ... Does the gradle actually download their files if so?

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905774/activity-main-xml-not-showing-and-gradle-doesnt-finish-initial-build

Comment: Yea... I tried both of the answers but it doesn't work... :p

Answer (score 2):

***In Android Studio try to go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and restart.
this will help u surely***

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio try to go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to try that option
Go to Build-> Clean Project
After clean your project complete
Go to Build-> Rebuild Project

IF that thing does not solve the problem then 
Please 
Go to File->Invalidate Cache/Restart-> Invalidate and restart
Actually

Android Studio makes a lot of files as caches and does not delete them. This can cause trouble when there is a need to make new files, so clearing caches will clear the old cache and make Android Studio faster and Smooth.
Hope that will hep you

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Close all opened project and bring back `Android Studio Welcome Screen`.

[image: Step1]

**Step 2:**

Select `Configure`

[image: Step2]

**Step 3:**

Select `Restore Default Settings...(Restore and Restart)`

[image: Step3]

**Step 4:**

Setup Android Studio as new

***OR***

Install new version of Android Studio