# How do i use 3rd party programs/plugins on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

Sorry to ask, I'm a student very new to using android studio. I am creating a game using Gage and there is some functionality I need that I can only seem to get by installing 3rd party programs (The one I need right now is called Awaitility, but there are others).

Looking at Awaitility's website, the instructions for installing their software seems to assume anyone know's exactly how to do it for any software; simply saying "Gradle:" followed by a few lines of "testcompile" code. Which I tried to copy into my project and of course after that couldn't find any proof that something had been added. There were downloads as well but no indication of where to put the downloaded files and what to do with them.

Looked all over for beginner's guide to doing this and can't find anything. This may not be the ideal website for doing this but if someone could point me in the right direction or recommend a more suitable site to use that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55288415/edit) your post to include links to the frameworks/libraries you are using. It may also help to understand [build dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) but that should have been covered if you were following any Android development tutorials using Android Studio.

Comment: Ah, sure will do in the future, thanks Morrison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of Gradle as a build tool, that has services that allows you to download Libraries from the web. (Thats not quite how it works but [READ THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio) if you would like more information)

```
    implementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:3.1.6'
```

So adding a new dependency to your .Gradle file tells Gradle that you're using that Library/module. Then, Gradle checks to see if that dependency is currently in your project files. If they are not, then it downloads them from a server. Also you can just test it out in your code to make sure that its there, ***Awaitility*** that is.

Its as simple as pasting the implemntation code into your gradle file and start using it. Since you're using Android Studios, there isn't anything special you need to do.

If you want to know if and where these files actually are installed, change the view from android to project, like so,

[image]

Then you can view all the external libraries.

[image]

As for Awaitility, that is just an advanced asynchronous library, there are other ways to do this [Like so](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Comment: Wow, what a perfect and polite answer, thanks very much! I'll give it a try now.