# Adding mavenCentral() to build.gradle file

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I create my Android Project on Android Studio 3.0.1 , and Now I try to Open it in 
Android Studio 3.5.3 to do that I Added this :

```
 mavenCentral()

 maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

to `build.gradle` file for Project in repositories two Parts (buildscript / repositories) and (allprojects/repositories) .

My Question is : Does the app need to test all its features again??

Answer (score 0):

For manual update:

```
buildscript {
          ...
          dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
          }
        }
```

No need to test anything because of `gradle` version change! But if downgrade the version then you might be change your some `api`,`dependencies` for lower `gradle` version.

**Gradle:**

`Gradle` is an advanced build toolkit for android that manages dependencies and allows you to define custom build logic. features are like. Customize, configure, and extend the build process. Create multiple `APKs` for your app with different features using the same project. Reuse code and resources.

And more about `gradle`: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24828666/6160172)